Head gasket blow temperature
I've made this search online without success. Very vague information only.
At what temperature does a head gasket get blown?

There is no "exact" temperature where a head gasket blows. It blows for reasons. It's not like it just gets to 250°F and lets go. It's usually a combination of factors which causes it to blow. Engines can quite often hit a peak temperature for a short period and if its allowed to cool down right away, will suffer no ill. A blown head gasket usually occurs due to a sustained amount of heat which is above a certain threshold. This causes metal to weaken and warp, which ultimately can cause the head gasket to blow.
A head gasket can blow for reasons of not overheating. For instance, the Honda D17 engine (2001-2005 Civic) was known for blown head gaskets when people would use other than the Smurf juice which Honda prescribed (blue colored coolant). The regular coolant (green stuff) would eat through the head gasket material and cause it to start leaking into the cylinder. Usually it was just a small amount of coolant which would leak into the cylinder, so if you kept the coolant up to where it should be, you'd not have any overheating problems.
I'm sure there's a myriad of ways to get to a blown head gasket. Overheating is just one way and it's not set in stone what amount of heat it takes for the head gasket to let loose. It happens when it happens and no two engines are going to let go at the same time.
